# How to limit draggable area in d3?

Tags: d3.js, draggable, drag

I have a draggable element in d3, but I want to limit the draggable area to the borders of the svg, so that it never goes out of view. Is this possible? Here's a jsfiddle with no limit on where the element can be dragged:

https://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/34TKg/

```
var drag1 = d3.behavior.drag()
        .origin(function() { 
            var t = d3.select(this);
            return {x: t.attr("x") + d3.transform(t.attr("transform")).translate[0],
                    y: t.attr("y") + d3.transform(t.attr("transform")).translate[1]};
        })
        .on("drag", function(d,i) {
            d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(d,i){
                return "translate(" + [ d3.event.x,d3.event.y ] + ")"
            })
        });

group.call(drag1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice clean JSFiddle - makes it easy to help you!

You can do so manually given that you know the dimensions of the container and the element you want to drag.

In essence you can check whether the potential new location of your dragged object will going beyond the bounds of the container. If so, then set the element's position to values that will make it be fully visible inside the contairer.

I have made a JSFiddle showcasing it: https://jsfiddle.net/0sga1ypc/

Most of the my updates are made in the callback function to the `drag` event:

```
    .on("drag", function(d,i) {
        var left = d3.event.x
        if (left + groupWidth + strokeWidth > svgWidth) {
            left = svgWidth - groupWidth - strokeWidth
        } else if (d3.event.x < 0) {
            left = 0
        }
        var top = d3.event.y
        if (top + groupHeight + strokeWidth > svgHeight) {
          top = svgHeight - groupHeight - strokeWidth
        } else if (d3.event.y < 0) {
          top = 0
        }
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", function(d,i){
            return "translate(" + [ left,top ] + ")"
        })
    });
```

The only other changes I have made is to save relevant dimension values into variables, so that they are not writte out multiple times.

Hope this helps!